# What is needed for a minimal systemd boot to launch getty on a virtual console?

Tags: boot, systemd

For SysV `init`, I need `/etc/inittab` respawning getty entries, the `/sbin/init` binary, the binaries and shared libraries for the shell, `login`, the `getty`, the PAM/security/shadow stuff, and a few device files.

For `upstart` I need pretty much the same requirements, but instead of `/etc/inittab`, I have a few `*.conf` files under `/etc/init`: one *.conf that `start on startup` that sets a runlevel with `telinit`, and one *.conf for each tty that start/respawn `getty` on that tty on the appropriate runlevels.

What configuration and binaries do I need for `systemd` `init`?

The documentation I find all seems to be focused on how to use an already-installed system to start and stop services.

A minimal list of files to copy (except the kernel/initrd) from a running *Arch* or *fedora* installation would do fine, but I cannot seem to find that kind of information about `systemd`.

---

What I would like to know is, for `systemd`, what files are required, and what must they contain, to start a login shell after an initramfs does it's `switch_root` call to the `systemd` `/sbin/init`.

---

Example for `upstart`, the binaries and two `*.conf` files:

File `/etc/init/whatever.conf`:

```
start on startup
emits runlevel
task
script
  telinit 2
end script
```

File `/etc/init/tty1.conf`:

```
start on runlevel [12345]
respawn
exec /sbin/agetty -8 --noclear 38400 tty1 linux
```

---

Example for `sysvinit`, the binaries and 1 conf file named `/etc/inittab`:

```
id:2:initdefault:
c1:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty1 linux
```

---

Now I'm after the `systemd` equivalent.

I assume at least 1 `*.service` file is needed somewhere, with a `[Service]` entry containing `ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I linux` and `Restart=always`, but what else is needed?

Comment: Now there is a recent RedHat knowledge base article (754933) describing the systemd boot at this URL: [Overview of systemd for RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/articles/754933)

Comment: It is so depressingly to see how people blow up a single configuration line into a big mess and call it improvement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, `systemd` is not a traditional unix `init`. Systemd is so much more, so it's a bit unfair to compare the two.

To answer the question, what appears to be necessary are some binaries and the following configuration files:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/basic.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/console-getty.service
```

issuing `systemctl enable console-getty.service getty@tty2.service` then creates these symlinks:

```
/etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/getty@tty2.service -> /lib/systemd/system/getty@service
/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/console-getty.service -> /lib/systemd/system/console-getty.service
```

**NOTE**: To utilize `systemd`'s special features for starting `agetty` dynamically, on-demand when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and so on, it appears that you must also have at least these two files:

```
/etc/systemd/logind.conf
/lib/systemd/system/autovt@.service
```

where `autovt@.service` is a symlink to `getty@.service`.

### Contents of configuration files:

The `default.target`, `getty.target`, `sysinit.target` files can be empty except for the `[Unit]` tag and (probably) `Description=xxx`.

`basic.target` also contains dependency information:

```
[Unit]
Description=Basic System
Requires=sysinit.target
Wants=sockets.target timers.target paths.target slices.target
After=sysinit.target sockets.target timers.target paths.target slices.target
```

I'm not sure if the references to targets that don't exist as files are needed or not. They are described on the [`systemd.special(7)`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html) man page.

---

`console-getty.service`: (Special case for agetty on the console)

```
[Unit]
Description=Console Getty
After=systemd-user-sessions.service plymouth-quit-wait.service
Before=getty.target

[Service]
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear --keep-baud console 115200,38400,9600 $TERM
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
UtmpIdentifier=cons
TTYPath=/dev/console
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
SendSIGHUP=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=getty.target
```

---

`getty@.service`: (generic config for all getty services except console)

```
[Unit]
Description=Getty on %I
After=systemd-user-sessions.service plymouth-quit-wait.service
Before=getty.target
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes
ConditionPathExists=/dev/tty0

[Service]
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
UtmpIdentifier=%I
TTYPath=/dev/%I
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYVTDisallocate=no
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
SendSIGHUP=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=getty.target
DefaultInstance=tty1
```

---

Finally you probably need a few of these special binaries (I haven't tried which ones are crucial):

```
/lib/systemd/systemd (/sbin/init usually points to this)
/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent
/lib/systemd/systemd-user-sessions
/lib/systemd/systemd-vconsole-setup
/lib/systemd/systemd-update-utmp
/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep
/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl
/lib/systemd/systemd-initctl
/lib/systemd/systemd-reply-password
/lib/systemd/systemd-ac-power
/lib/systemd/systemd-activate
/lib/systemd/systemd-backlight
/lib/systemd/systemd-binfmt
/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart
/lib/systemd/systemd-bus-proxyd
/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump
/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup
/lib/systemd/systemd-fsck
/lib/systemd/systemd-hostnamed
/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-gatewayd
/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote
/lib/systemd/systemd-localed
/lib/systemd/systemd-machined
/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load
/lib/systemd/systemd-multi-seat-x
/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online
/lib/systemd/systemd-quotacheck
/lib/systemd/systemd-random-seed
/lib/systemd/systemd-readahead
/lib/systemd/systemd-remount-fs
/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
/lib/systemd/systemd-rfkill
/lib/systemd/systemd-shutdown
/lib/systemd/systemd-shutdownd
/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd
/lib/systemd/systemd-timedated
/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
/lib/systemd/systemd-update-done
```

---

To summarize the systemd start process, I think it works something like this:

1. systemd locates `basic.target` (or all `*.target` files?)
2. dependencies are resolved based on `WantedBy=`, `Wants=`, `Before=`, `After=`... directives in the `[Install]` section of the `*.service` and `*.target` configuration files.
3. `*.service`s that should start (that are not "special" services), have a `[Service]` section with a `ExecStart=` directive, that points out the executable to start.

Comment: AFAIK the `[Install]` section is not used by the boot sequence, only by `systemctl enable`. What the boot looks at is the symlinks in `/etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/`, which are created by `systemctl enable`.

Answer (score 6):

`systemd` automatically creates a getty when you switch to the terminals, up to a certain maximum number. The default is 6 (so you get automatically a getty for alt+f1 to alt+f6). If you want to change this parameter you can edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to change `NAutoVTs` parameter to some other number (max 12)

If you want a getty to spawn even if you don't manually switch you can add a symlink to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` to the `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/` directory:

```
ln -sf /usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty9.service
```

this will result in the `getty.target` requiring one more `getty@` service.
A target is a collection of services that need to be spawned, replacement of runlevels which supports dependencies. The default target depends on `getty.target`

See at [systemd FAQ in ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_FAQ#How_do_I_change_the_default_number_of_gettys.3F)

**edit:**
I researched a bit more in [the documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/).

At boot the `systemd` daemon loads all systems in the `default` target and their dependencies. A target is defined by the files

```
/etc/systemd/system/default.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target
```

A target has a list of attached services specified by symlinks in the directories

```
/etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants
/usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target.wants
```

The `/etc` version overrides the distribution defaults in `/usr/lib`. Only one of the `.target` files is required, while none of the directory is required

`getty` is just one of the services among others which can be run by init scripts. In the distribution I checked (fedora, arch) `getty` is run in two different ways:

1. Started by specific scripts for each terminal (links to the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` file in which [the tty name is substituted in by `systemd` from the link filename](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html))
2. Automatically brought up as needed by the `logind` when the user switch to a virtual terminal (similar to the way old `inetd` brought up services only when a request arrives). `logind` is a different daemon distributed with `systemd`, and reads its configuration from the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file.

Hope this is satisfying.

Comment: I want to know which files are needed, and what they shall contain. Could you summarize your answer with a list of files that are required and what causes them to be read in what order? I'm missing info about what needs to be found in that directory. I'll try to elaborate my question a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @MattBianco you are needlessly hostile toward `systemd`. I'm researching a bit of it and it looks pretty straightforward, once you understand how stuff works

Comment: Yes, I'm spoiled by documentation from other open source projects. I'm sorry for sounding hostile. It's just frustrating that there seems to be no simple document explaining the boot process. (I understand now that it is because systemd is not simple.) In a humorous way I'd like to comment that it is perhaps `systemd` that is hostile, as in performing a hostile takeover of the way an open system starts. It turns GNU/Linux away from Unix. Not saying that that's a bad thing, but it is very different from how things have traditionally been. And googling around a bit indicates that I'm not alone.

Answer (score 2):

After some experiments I found that one target-service pair is enough to boot into. Copied from `emergency.service`:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Description=shell.service: Console and Login

[Service]
Environment=HOME=/root
WorkingDirectory=-/root
ExecStart=-/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sulogin-shell
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/openvt -f -c 16 agetty tty16
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/openvt -f -c 17 -- agetty -p tty17
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/openvt -f -c 18 -- agetty -p -a USER tty18
Type=idle
StandardInput=tty-force
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
#KillMode=process
KillMode=control-group
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
SendSIGHUP=yes
```

For testing: renaming the distro's unit dir to `/lib/systemd/systemDEACT` is a simple but radical way to reduce the number of units/unit-files from 200 to 10; there are still some false ones:

```
  UNIT                    LOAD      ACTIVE     SUB       DESCRIPTION
  dev-sda3.device         loaded    activating tentative /dev/sda3
  -.mount                 loaded    active     mounted   Root Mount
  tmp.mount               loaded    active     mounted   /tmp
  init.scope              loaded    active     running   System and Service Manager
  io.service              loaded    inactive   dead      io: usbhid kmod for keyboard
  remount.service         loaded    inactive   dead      remount: rw for / and tmpfs for /tmp
  shell.service           loaded    active     running   shell.service: Console and Login
  -.slice                 loaded    active     active    Root Slice
  system.slice            loaded    active     active    System Slice
* systemd-journald.socket not-found inactive   dead      systemd-journald.socket
* local-fs-pre.target     not-found inactive   dead      local-fs-pre.target
* local-fs.target         not-found inactive   dead      local-fs.target
  mini.target             loaded    active     active    "mini": Minimal Boot and Shell
* swap.target             not-found inactive   dead      swap.target
* umount.target           not-found inactive   dead      umount.target
```

Beside `shell.service` (see top) I made a `remount.service` and `io.service`; the `modprobe usbhid` is crucial for my (any?) USB keyboard. The remount service needs a sync with the fsck in arch's initrd script for the remount and with tmp.mount for `/tmp`. I also have to find out where to place that `rw` correctly on the KCL...in the meantime I get a couple of green `[OK]` at bootup from two *oneshot* and one *idle* services.

The dependency tree is:

```
mini.target
* |-io.service
* |-remount.service
* `-shell.service
```

With my `remount` redundant/conflicting with KCL and `io` just doing `modprobe usbhid` (which can be done with a `ExecStart...` in `shell.service` also), this is just one target/service pair. Plus the `default.target` link if you don't add `systemd.unit=mini.target` on the kernel CL.

I spent hours chasing the *tentative* `dev-sdaX.device` (the only, root partition); now I think this is halfways normal.

`-.mount` and `-.slice` and `init.scope` are internal and make sense.

`tmp.mount` I think is generated in `/run`.

The `not-found` journald, local-fs, swap and umount units don't seem to hurt systemd; with `--state loaded` they are not shown. They probably should be created as first additional units. But how define `local-fs` when root partition comes already checked from initrd? Can a boot with initrd be *minimal*?

`systemctl status` is also minimal. There is a slice, but only one (no user-X slices):

```
* archlinux
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Fri 2021-10-01 15:24:16 UTC; 3min 2s ago
   CGroup: /
           |-init.scope 
           | `-1 /sbin/init arch\x5cvmlinuz-linux
           `-system.slice 
             `-shell.service 
               |-215 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sulogin-shell
               |-219 bash
               |-220 agetty tty16
               |-222 agetty -p tty17
               |-225 agetty -p -a USER tty18
               `-238 systemctl status
```

With `KillMode` you can control what happens to the processes inside shell.service. The corresponding `ps axf` is:

```
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/init arch\vmlinuz-linux
  215 tty1     Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sulogin-shell
  219 tty1     S      0:00  \_ bash
  245 tty1     R+     0:00      \_ ps axf
  246 tty1     S+     0:00      \_ tail -8
  220 tty16    Ss+    0:00 agetty tty16
  222 tty17    Ss+    0:00 agetty -p tty17
  225 tty18    Ss+    0:00 agetty -p -a USER tty18
```

The `agetty`s have no parent - thanks to `openvt` ? - but still PID1/init/systemd keeps track of the pids. I was able to restart `shell.service` with different `KillMode`s.

A `ctrl-D` or `exit` on that sulogin-shell is not recommended...

And how can I stop all this?

After that radical dir-rename the `reboot` command "can not talk to init daemon" or so. A (copy of) `reboot.service` with action `reboot-force` (not reboot, not reboot-immediate) is the most direct way out, and sufficient for this test bootup (no journald running etc.). Sysvinit shutdown is not really elegant either, nor fast. `systemctl start reboot` then does the PID signalling and killing and a `sync` (I guess), but no otherwise ordered shutdown. That would be with a "final" or "shutdown" target, from where you can go to CPU `reboot`, `poweroff` or `halt`. With or w/o shutdown-initramfs.

---

So `systemd` can start and run (and stop!) without journald, udevd and dbus and all these unit files, and `--user` instances. But it is hard to "supermask" (i.e. make go away) the 200 distro-units, and then there still are some traces of built-in units and built-in logic.

**TL;DR:** `emergency.target`, `DefaultDependencies=no`, `openvt`